# HTML Agility Pack - Get Page Summary

Tags: html, parsing, html-agility-pack

How would I use the HTML Agility Pack to get the First Paragraph of text from the body of an HTML file.  I'm building a DIGG style link submission tool, and want to get the title and the first paragraph of text.  Title is easy, any suggestions for how I might get the first paragraph of text from the body?  I guess it could be within P or DIV depending on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this html that you control?  If so, you could give the p an id or a class and find it via

```
//p[@id=\"YOUR ID\"] or //p[@class=\"YOUR CLASS\"]
```

EDIT:
Since you don't control the html, maybe the below will work.  It takes all the HtmlTextNodes and tries to find a grouping of text greater than the threshold specified.  It's far from perfect but might get you going in the right direction.

```
String summary = FindSummary(page.DocumentNode);

private const int THRESHOLD = 50;
private String FindSummary(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node) {
    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes) {
        if (childNode.GetType() == typeof(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlTextNode)) {
            if (childNode.InnerText.Length >= THRESHOLD) {
                return childNode.InnerText;
            }
        }

        String summary = FindSummary(childNode);
        if (summary.Length >= THRESHOLD) {
            return summary;
        }
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I don't control the HTML, users can submit any page they like, so I don't know what the ID or class of the container will be

Answer (score 1):

The agility pack uses xpath for querying the html load you just use a simple xpath statement.  Something like...

```
HtmlDocument htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmldoc.LoadHtml(content);

HtmlNodeCollection firstParagraph = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[1]");
```